# Executing workflow commands for GitHub Actions using a Python script

Tags: python, logging, github-actions

I am trying to log a [warning message](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-a-warning-message) in my GitHub Actions workflow using a Python script.

The script writes the following output in the workflow:

```
::warning file="./german.ini",title="Sub-Section 'close_button' of 'about_csprite_popup' Not Found"
```

using the `sys.stdout.write` function in Python's `sys` module, but apparently it is logged as a normal text:

[image: github actions un-formatted output screenshot]

as opposed to the formatted text as expected here:

[image: github-action-utils python module test screenshot]

My Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# Requires Python v3 Interpreter

import os
import sys
import glob
import configparser

ConfigStructure = {
    "file_menu": [ "file", "new", "open" ],
    "help_menu": [ "help", "about", "github" ],
    "open_file_popup": [ "open_file" ],
    "new_document_popup": [
        "title", "width_input", "height_input",
        "ok_button", "cancel_button"
    ],
    "about_csprite_popup": [
        "title", "contributors_header", "contributors_paragraph",
        "contributors_link", "os_projects_header", "os_projects_text",
        "close_button"
    ],
    "unicode_range": [ "range" ]
}

Files = []
ExitCode = 0

for f in glob.glob("./*.ini"):
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        Files.append(f)

for f in Files:
    try:
        config=configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(f)

        for Section in ConfigStructure:
            if not Section in config:
                sys.stdout.write("::warning file=\"" + f + "\",title=\"Section '" + Section + "' Not Found\"\n")
                break

            for SubSection in ConfigStructure[Section]:
                if not SubSection in config[Section]:
                    sys.stdout.write("::warning file=\"" + f + "\",title=\"Sub-Section '" + SubSection + "' of '" + Section + "' Not Found\"\n")

    except Exception as e:
        sys.stdout.write(f"::error file='{f}',title='Unhandled Error Occurred'::'{str(e)}'\n")
        ExitCode = 1

sys.exit(ExitCode)
```

My GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
name: Lint
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        submodules: recursive

    - name: Install Python
      run: |
        sudo apt-get update -y
        sudo apt-get install python3 -y

    - name: Lint Languages Files
      run: |
        python3 ValidateLangFiles.py
```

Comment: Your warning doesn't look that much like the example in the docs, nor the error in the same file (does that one work?) - it's not entirely explicit what the syntax is, but perhaps the delimiting :: are important?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) The really low contrast in the images makes them hard to use even for those of us without vision problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, the expected format is as follows:

```
::warning file={name},line={line},endLine={endLine},title={title}::{message}
```

With example code as:

```
Write-Output "::warning file=app.js,line=1,col=5,endColumn=7::Missing semicolon"
```

---

Your code does not appear to be using the correct format. It is missing, in at least one case, missing the ending `::` before the `{message}` portion of the expected format.

```py
sys.stdout.write("::warning file=\"" + f + "\",title=\"Section '" + Section + "' Not Found\"\n")
```

Should instead be something like this:

```py
print(f'::warning file={f},title=Section {Section}::Not found')
```

You should also consider setting the variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` in your yaml, to prevent partial buffering of your output:

```yaml
env:
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED: "1"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! apparently as you pointed out, my format was wrong, i wasn't outputting the body text for the warnings.

everything works now!